# Blank Purple Screen When Booting Into Ubuntu After Installation

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, nvidia, 19.04

im trying to dual boot ubuntu with windows 10 in my ASUS S430FN Laptop, the installation went right but after i rebooted and select to boot ubuntu, is goes **blank purple screen, not even any ubuntu logo or any error messages.**

i've tried anything like **nomodeset, nouveau.modeset = 0, changing the quiet splash to no splash, changing the acpi to zero etc.**

im using **ASUS S430FN Laptop with intel i7-8565U, 8 gigs of ram, 512 SSD, NVIDIA Geforce MX150, and original windows 10 version 1903.
im trying to install desktop ubuntu 19.04**

can anyone help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CHECK THE ASUS WEBSITE FOR A FIRMWARE UPDATE!!!

Here is a complete video [about this problem, actually for an Asus Zenbook] but almost every Asus with 8565U has this problem. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbxrSaclKRc).

**Summary of the fix:**
Add the boot parameter: `dis_ucode_ldr` to `/etc/default/grub` and then execute: `update-grub`.

More info [here at LaunchPad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1829620).